# Guitar signal preamplifier - ADC input to STM32F4

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, stm32, dsp, aliasing

This is for a DSP project. I am trying to prepare my guitar signal for as best as possible ADC response in order to detect harmonics to the 5th of the highest note of the guitar (1175 Hz for 22 frets), which is about 5875 Hz. This means that I need to be sampling at about 58.75 kHz, which is possible with the microcontroller and it's DSP functions.

I am using an STM32F407 Discovery board.

So far, I have not come across any solutions that I am happy with.

Considerations that are important:

- Guitar output impedance: about 1M ohm.
- Anti-aliasing for the ADC
- Guitar signal of 500mV Vp-p max
- ADC input range 0-3.3V
- 5V single supply
- Frequency range from 82Hz and 5875 Hz

Does anyone have any suggestions of a circuit that I can use? I have TL082, LM358 and LM741 opamps available, but I am open to other suggestions.

The goal of this element of the projects is to be able to use the first 5 harmonics and a sampled period of the guitar signal for further DSP.

This is what I have come up with so far - although I believe it's far from ideal. 
[image: First attempt schematic]

This is a closed loop bode plot of the system. Couple of things that worry me are the massive phase differences at the corner frequencies, and the slope of the low pass filter and it's stop frequency. The cutoffs are at 10Hz and 10kHz

[image: Frequency graph]

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be looking to filter out signals above 20kHz, or sample at 200 kHz (and even then you'll need a reasonably good filter). Doesn't seem easy to do well, but should absolutely be standard in audio DSP... Looks like the same question has been asked before, what is missing from those answers?

Comment: None of your opamps are useful here, the TL082 would be good as an input buffer but requires a lot of voltage headroom. The 741 is not an opamp, it's a piece of plastic with metal legs.

Comment: Can you get better opamps in? (Or where are you on this planet, for that matter?)

Comment: @SeanHoulihane I can filter out signals above 20kHz - 10 kHz was what I was thinking. Would prefer not to have to sample too high (am happy with around 50kHz) in order to maintain resolution at lower frequencies for DSP. What's missing in previous questions and answers: anti-aliasing, (proper) input impedance matching, low voltage single supply opamps.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel , Yes, I can get better opamps. I am in South Africa and have access to quite a lot. RS Components is one of my favourite suppliers. Any suggestions?

Comment: A guitar doesn't produce anywhere near 500mV P-P. More like 50mV. The highest note on a 22-fret guitar D above soprano top A, or 1173Hz at concert pitch.

Comment: This seems like an interesting approach for the initial input stage ["A Discrete FET Guitar Preamp" by J. Donald Tillman](http://www.till.com/articles/GuitarPreamp/), however, I couldn't find any sources for the Vishay/Siliconix J201 N-Channel JFET, which seems to be obsolete :-( I assume, once there is a reasonable buffer you could filter, as you say, at 10kHz. J. Donald Tillman wrote guitar pickups can drive quite large signals, " 2.0 Volts or so peak-to-peak if you're playing hard"; so would that not be an issue for you, or do you want the 'sound of clipping'?

Comment: @EJP - Regarding the "note", yes you're partially right. The note is the frequency of the first harmonic. There are loads of harmonics above this with high energy content. I'm interested in those up to the 5th, as mentioned. Regarding the voltage - you're just wrong. I just measured this, plucked really hard(er than normal) on my oscilloscope and measured about 300mVp-p. Neck pickup, Squire Strat single coil.

Comment: @gbulmer Thanks for the link! Have come across it, but I will investigate in more detail. Yes, I believe pickups can have a very high output (if I just think about a piezo for example - that's a lot of energy). I'm kind of just designing for my guitar right now, and I'm pretty sure I'm not getting anything over 500mVp-p - so I think clipping will be okay. I don't want clipping.

Comment: Your output protection, D1, isn't going to save you. It's feeding from a 1k source into a 500k sink. 1k trumps 500k.

Comment: @Transistor I see. It works on the sim though?

Comment: @makepeace: It's probably the op-amp maxing out. It can't get close to the +5 rail.

Comment: @Transistor You're totally right - it actually even wasn't working in the sim. Didn't try a big enough amplitude. Fixed.

Comment: "There are loads of harmonics... with high energy content." - What relative amplitude can we expect for the 25th harmonic of 1175Hz?  If you just want to 'detect' harmonics, why are you worried about phase?

Comment: @BruceAbbott - I'm not worried about the 25th. I'm worried about the 5th, and recording a well characterised waveform of the note - which has the 5th. As far as I understand 10 x that frequency is a good bet...

Comment: @pipe, not fair. The 741 is a precision signal degradation device which is designed to take a wide range of high quality input signals and ruin them.

Answer (score 1):

> I have TL082, LM358 and LM741 opamps available

The TL082 and LM741 require high voltage power supplies, but the LM358 works fine on 5V so it should be OK.

Rather than trying to limit the ADC input voltage with diodes I would simply use a voltage divider to bring it down. The op amp's bias voltage is then set to the value that produces maximum undistorted output (which is *not* 2.5V, because the LM358 can only pull up to ~1.5V below Vcc).

Here is my modified version of your circuit:-

[image]

R1 and R2 set the op amp bias to 1.79V. Maximum output voltage of U2 is 3.5V. R3 and R9 divide this down to 3.3V.

The only other change I made was reducing the value of the inter-stage coupling capacitor (C3 in my circuit) from 22uF to 2.2uF. This provides a stepper low frequency roll off, but my main reason for changing it was to avoid having to use an electrolytic capacitor.

Here is the ac analysis:-

[image]

If you are only interested in the frequency components of the signal (not the actual wave shape) then phase differences shouldn't worry you.

The slopes of the filter in the simulation are a bit misleading because the simulated input is a low impedance AC generator. Guitar pickups have high inductance with a relatively low self-resonant frequency, typically between 8-12kHz. Above self-resonance the pickup's frequency response drops away sharply, so higher harmonics are attenuated much more than you might think.

Without simulating the pickup you won't find out what the true response is until you test the circuit with a real guitar. The good news is that it will probably do a better job than what the simulator is telling you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Looks much better! I've added model of the guitar pickup (more or less) and it's looking better. Regarding the phase differences - I am interested in the wave shape. The sampled wave is going to be used to modulate an output. As much of the signal character as possible is required to be retained. How can I reduce the phase differences? Probably can't right? I've simulated the time response with your modifications, and without the diodes - if the input is 1Vp-p - my ADC gets slammed with about 4V. Probably not a good idea to take those diodes out?

Comment: If the output voltage is too high you can reduce it by changing the voltage divider ratio (increase R3 and/or reduce R9). But I bet you are not using the correct LM358 model. Since it drops _at least_ 1.1V (more when loaded) it is not possible to get 4V out when Vcc is 5V.

Comment: "I am interested in the wave shape... to modulate an output" - Pity you didn't mention this earlier, but I'm not sure it's relevant anyway. In a normal listening environment dramatic phase changes occur (especially at the high end) and nobody notices because the human ear detects _frequencies_, not waveforms. But if the wave _shape_ is so important to you then just make the amp as flat as possible - and don't be concerned about aliasing because it will only occur above the 25th harmonic (of 1175Hz) which is very weak and won't noticeably affect the shape of the digitized waveform.

Comment: "The goal of this element of the projects is to be able to use the first 5 harmonics and **a sampled period of the guitar signal** for further DSP." In any case, thanks for your tips. I managed to develop a circuit that works pretty well in the application with the answers on this page.